# VB statement fails to update field in Access 2016

Tags: database, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

The problem is with data fields need to be checked to determine if the "Transaction_Amount" is an expense or Income.  This information is stored in the "categories" and the table associates a budget category as an "expense/Income".

Based on the "Income/expense" notation the actual transaction amount is populated as an expense (-) or Income (+) and updated in the "Account_Trasactions" table as either an expense or Income Item.  In each case, the value is added to the existing value in the Account_Transactions" Table in the record associated with that budget.

So the goal is to track all budget categories as "budgeted" - "actual" = "Balance".

Here is my code and it fails to update the field Actual_amount on the form!

```
Private Sub Actual_amount_GotFocus()
'check for expense or income and adjust actual ammount of transaction'

 [iif [category].[income/expense]="expense", (actual_Amount)=((Transaction_amount)*-1),actual_amount = Transaction_amount)]

 'Update category table'

 [Category].[Actual_Amount] [Actual_Amount]

End Sub
```

What am I doing wrong??

Comment: is this part right? iif (two i's)

Comment: That's not VBA, just some expressions, that surely don't compile without errors.

Comment: IIF is the correct Syntax for Access.

Comment: I have checked the code and when I run it I receive the following message.   **Run-time-error '2465'  G:\Working folder\Pack 150 DBMS\Pack150.accdb can't find field '|1' referred to in your expression. ** At that point, the program crashes.

Comment: Well, I see three (3) different spellings -- 1) actual_Amount  2) actual_amount 3)  Actual_Amount .  Do you have  Option Explicit  ?  It is  your friend.

Comment: I corrected that problem, and still no change.  Thank you for your advice.